# Angular how to output a string with {{}}?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

for example:
js:

```
var str = "this my mark {{a}} {{e}} {{i} {{o}} {{u}}, select one!";
$scope.tip = str;
```

html:

```
<p>{{tip}}</p>
```

how to make the output is `this my mark {{a}} {{e}} {{i} {{o}} {{u}}, select one!`?

Answer (score 2):

Add `ngNonBindable` attribute to the element who's content you don't want to be compiled or bind.

Comment: thanks a lot! I have to use a inefficient method: `string.replace(/{/g, '{&shy').replace(/}/g, '}&shy')`, now I can deal it with `<span ng-non-bindable>'+string+'</span>`